# mvn-gae-plugin suddenly broken

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, maven-gae-plugin

I'm not sure what happened but I've made not changes to my pom and have only done a clean install but now running my app with `mvn gae:run` gives me the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.4:run (default-cli) on project geoip-service: Execution default-cli of goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.4:run failed: Plugin net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.4 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.kindleit:gae-runtime:pom:1.7.5: Could not find artifact net.kindleit:maven-gae-parent:pom:0.9.6-SNAPSHOT in genius (our_own_repo_here)`

I'm using the 1.7.2 version of the sdk so I'm not sure where the 1.7.5 could be coming from.

Comment: I am experimenting the same problem. Maybe this problem has to do with this pull request commited 2 days ago: https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin/pull/64
https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin/commit/6c708b5c86a879227d36f84b97eac9afe9d6d380

Comment: Had the same problem using plugin 0.9.5 with gAE 1.8.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the time being, you can use this ugly hack

```
<properties>
    <gae.version>1.7.5</gae.version>
    <gae-runtime.version>1.7.5.1</gae-runtime.version>
</properties>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.gae.plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
            <unpackVersion>${gae.version}</unpackVersion>
            <serverId>appengine.google.com</serverId>
            <appDir>${webappDirectory}</appDir>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>${gae-runtime.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you shed light on why this workaround is needed? I should be able to use any sdk, right? Is it a bug in the plugin?

Comment: that was a while ago. I think that particular release of the maven-gae-plugin was referring to a beta version of the gae sdk, so by explicitly passing a version ourselves, we make maven find the correct version. Perhaps it's not needed anymore now, I haven't tried

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what the issue was, I.e. who was pulling in gae-runtime of version 1.7.5 but this is the work around that worked for me. Add the following under your maven-gae-plugin in profile/build/plugins/plugin etc.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
        <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: See Github issue [here][1] 


  [1]: https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin/issues/67#issuecomment-14149465