# Maven GAE archetype not working

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, maven-3, maven-gae-plugin

I'm trying to use google app engine for simple spring based application with maven. I have found that there is maven archetype avaible for that kind of web application (without spring, but this I can add on my own): Maven GAE.

So I used the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=net.kindleit -DarchetypeArtifactId=gae-archetype-jsp -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=form -DarchetypeRepository=http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository
```

However, when i tried to use "mvn gae:run" it doesn't work and I don't know how to solve this missing requirement:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 7.444s
    [INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 02 21:04:22 CET 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5:run (default-cli) on project form: Execution default-cli of goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5:run failed: Plugin net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.5 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.kindleit:gae-runtime:pom:1.7.5: Failure to find net.kindleit:maven-gae-parent:pom:0.9.6-SNAPSHOT in http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5:run (default-cli) on project form: Execution default-cli of goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5:run failed: Plugin net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.5 ()
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5:run failed: Plugin net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.5 ()
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.5 ()
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:211)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:78)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.5 ()
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:258)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:308)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:199)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.kindleit:gae-runtime:pom:1.7.5
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:331)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:240)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Failure to find net.kindleit:maven-gae-parent:pom:0.9.6-SNAPSHOT in http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:813)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:664)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:310)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:322)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find net.kindleit:maven-gae-parent:pom:0.9.6-SNAPSHOT in http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find net.kindleit:maven-gae-parent:pom:0.9.6-SNAPSHOT in http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:230)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:204)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:427)
        ... 37 more
```

A can add that I tried to use diffrent versions of maven-gae-plugin but without success....

Comment: After some time i found solution [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094381/mvn-gae-plugin-suddenly-broken

Comment: After some time i found solution [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094381/mvn-gae-plugin-suddenly-broken

Comment: oh cool, I hadn't seen your comments...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094381/mvn-gae-plugin-suddenly-broken/15123921#15123921).

Can you try this?

```xml
<properties>
  <gae.version>1.7.5</gae.version>
  <gae-runtime.version>1.7.5.1</gae-runtime.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
  <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.gae.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
        <unpackVersion>${gae.version}</unpackVersion>
        <serverId>appengine.google.com</serverId>
        <appDir>${webappDirectory}</appDir>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${gae-runtime.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What the heck. I have no idea what it does. But it apparently works. Thanks.

Comment: @xybrek, keep an eye on next version of the plugin 1.7.6, there's a pull request so it may become available any day

Comment: @KarelBílek, thanks. If you look into the plugin's pom.xml, that might shed a light, basically they bumped the version of the GAE plugin to 1.5.1 but there's no GAE maven repo with that version for java, therefore the two numbers have decoupled, at least for this version