# Can't run maven com.google.appengine.archetypes:guestbook-archetype:1.7.7 on Windows

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

I want to create an App Engine project using Maven as described here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven
but encounter some problems.

`mvn -v` outputs

```
Maven home: D:\Shared\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_13, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre
Default locale: de_AT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

and

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

also works as expected, however when I enter

```
com.google.appengine.archetypes:guestbook-archetype
```

nothing happens afterwards, meaning it prompts again "*Choose a number or apply filter [..]*".

I am however able to create a project using a modified command from the question [Maven GAE archetype not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178931/maven-gae-archetype-not-working) that is:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.appengine.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=guestbook-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.7.7
```

The output is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>
>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<
<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom --
-
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] Archetype repository missing. Using the one from [com.google.appengine.ar
chetypes:guestbook-archetype:1.7.7] found in catalog remote
```

Then it lets me define the 4 values for the 4 properties and then prints several lines that also state `[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS`.

However, when I then switch to the directory (using `cd a` in this example) and run `mvn verify` or `mvn appengine:devserver` the following test fails:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.526 sec

Results :

Failed tests:   testDoGet(a.GuestbookServletTest): expected:<Hello, test[]

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.826s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun May 05 21:47:32 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
10:test (default-test) on project a: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Shared\maven-projects\a\target\surefire-reports for t
he individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

In the file `D:\Shared\maven-projects\a\target\surefire-reports\a.GuestbookServletTest.txt` I noticed the following:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<Hello, test[]
> but was:<Hello, test[
]
>
```

As Hex, it is

```
6a 75 6e 69 74 2e 66 72 61 6d 65 77 6f 72 6b 2e 43 6f 6d 70 61 72 69 73 6f 6e 46 61 69 6c 75 72 65 3a 20 65 78 70 65 63 74 65 64 3a 3c 48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 74 65 73 74 5b 5d 0a 3e 20 62 75 74 20 77 61 73 3a 3c 48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 74 65 73 74 5b 0d 5d 0a 3e
```

**As you can see, in the actual output there is a `0d` character between the square brackets. In the expectation, there isn't anything between the square brackets.** I looked it up and it seems to be a **carriage return**.

What should I do?
Could this be an issue with my platform that is `Cp1252` and not `UTF-8`?

I also tried generating the project setting `file.encoding` like

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.appengine.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=guestbook-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.7.7 -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

and even

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.appengine.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=guestbook-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.7.7 -Dfile.encoding="Cp1252"
```

but there still is that exta `0d` character in the output.

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me getting this to work.

Comment: I believe you are starting with Google App Engine, IMHO, please do not use maven, instead use Google plugin for eclipse, that is rock solid and easy to understand.

Comment: I am not starting with App Engine, I'm using it for almost 2 years with the Eclipse plugin. Now I want to use maven. I am new to maven, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out there is a bug in the JUnit test.

Line `73` in `GuestbookServletTest.java` has to be changed from:

```
assertEquals("Hello, " + currentUser.getNickname() + "\n", stringWriter.toString());
```

to

```
assertEquals("Hello, " + currentUser.getNickname() + System.getProperty("line.separator"), stringWriter.toString());
```

because Windows uses `\r\n` as a path seperator. I filed a bug report at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9272 , in case someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try by adding the following lines in your pom.xml

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.build.resourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.resourceEncoding>
<maven.compile.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compile.encoding>
</properties>
```

you can follow [this](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/UTF-8-Test-Mystery-td4889940.html) thread for similar discussion

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Doing some more investigation, I found out it was a bug with path seperators used for expections. See my answer for details. Thanks anyway :)