# Why can't I deploy to app engine using maven-gae-plugin?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, gwt-platform, maven-gae-plugin

I'm trying to deploy my maven project for the first time.

Using the maven-gae-plugin, as was set up in an archetype project, so it should work. However I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.6:deploy (default-cli) on project
>   UsavAppV7: Execution default-cli of goal
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.6:deploy failed: Plugin
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.6 or one of its dependencies could
>   not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.6 (): Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for net.kindleit:gae-runtime:pom:1.7.5: Could not find
>   artifact net.kindleit:maven-gae-parent:pom:0.9.6-SNAPSHOT in
>   maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/) ->
>   [Help 1]

I am using appengine 1.8.0 (not sure what the 1.7.5 bit means). Have tried with the -U switch and the same thing happens.

I note that maven is looking in the maven2-repository for the plugin snapshot, so perhaps wrong version or location?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178931/maven-gae-archetype-not-working/15182650#15182650

Comment: Found it about half an hour ago and trying it now. I don't really want to have to use 1.7.5 in an ideal world though, but it looks like a good workaround for now

Comment: Good luck. I'm having lots of trouble with GAE + java 7 + eclipse + maven http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117440/understanding-how-to-resolve-inconsistent-stackmap-frames-exception/19117957?noredirect=1#comment28826938_19117957

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my pom did the trick, and allowed me to use the latest version of the sdk and runtime:

```
<gae.version>1.8.6</gae.version>
<gae-runtime.version>1.8.6</gae-runtime.version>

<plugin>
  <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.gae.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
        <unpackVersion>${gae.version}</unpackVersion>
        <serverId>appengine.google.com</serverId>
        <appDir>${webappDirectory}</appDir>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${gae-runtime.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```